# store tag value from git repo into file

Tags: ruby, git, github

I am new to git and I have a repo stored on git. I want to implement version control the `tag` value that is available on git.

I have a file called`version.rb` which specifies the version of the plugin that I am currently using, which look like this :

`Version = "0.1.0"`

and the tag associated with this commit would be `"0.1.0"`.

Issue :

```
  Sometimes when I create a new tag for the repo, I would forget to update the value of `Version` in version.rb.
```

I want to update the `Version` value in `version.rb` to be the same value as a the tag value on the repo. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Changing a file in a tagged commit does not make the changed file part of the previously tagged commit. So if you change `version.rb` you still have to create another tagged version of your repo.

Looks like you just have to remember to bump the version in `version.rb`.